# vcpkg wxWidgets CMake linker error with libjpeg.a

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets, vcpkg

I'm trying to use wxWidgets on an arm64 macOS with vcpkg, CMake, and VS Code. Everything is wired up correctly because other vcpkg libraries include, link, and run fine. But, when I try to use wxWidgets there's a linking error.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.0)
project(main VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
set_property(TARGET main PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

The CMake error I get:

```
[build] [ 50%] Linking CXX executable main
[build] ld: library not found for -llibjpeg.a>
[build] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The value of the `wxWidgets_LIBRARIES` list (set by `find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)`):

```
-L/Users/myname/cpp/vcpkg/packages/wxwidgets_arm64-osx/lib;-pthread;/Users/myname/cpp/vcpkg/packages/wxwidgets_arm64-osx/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.1.a;/Users/myname/cpp/vcpkg/packages/wxwidgets_arm64-osx/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_qa-3.1.a;/Users/myname/cpp/vcpkg/packages/wxwidgets_arm64-osx/lib/libwx_baseu_net-3.1.a;/Users/myname/cpp/vcpkg/packages/wxwidgets_arm64-osx/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_html-3.1.a;/Users/myname/cpp/vcpkg/packages/wxwidgets_arm64-osx/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.1.a;/Users/myname/cpp/vcpkg/packages/wxwidgets_arm64-osx/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.a;/Users/myname/cpp/vcpkg/packages/wxwidgets_arm64-osx/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.a;-lwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.1;libjpeg.a>;libjpeg.a>;libpng.a>;libpng16d.a>;libz.a>;libz.a>;libtiff.a>;libtiffd.a>;liblzma.a>;liblzma.a>;libjpeg.a>;libjpeg.a>;libz.a>;libz.a>;m;-framework AudioToolbox;-framework WebKit;-lwx_baseu-3.1;libexpat.a>;libexpat.a>;libz.a>;libz.a>;-lwxregexu-3.1;libiconv.tbd;-framework CoreFoundation;-framework Security;-framework Carbon;-framework Cocoa;-framework IOKit;-framework QuartzCore;TIFF::TIFF;expat::expat;ZLIB::ZLIB;png_static
```

I don't have much experience with CMake, so I don't know what the right angle bracket is for, but is that the problem? Could its being the first non-full-path file in the list mean that it doesn't know where to look?

Comment: ***but is that the problem?*** I  don't believe  the problem is CMake related.  Does `libjpeg.a` exist on your  system?

Comment: @drescherjm Yes all the dependency libs like `libjpeg` for wxWidgets were automatically installed when vcpkg installed wxWidgets. `libjpeg.a` is at `/Users/myname/cpp/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib/libjpeg.a`. All the others like `libpng.a`, `libz.a`, and so on are there too right next to `libjpeg.a`.

Comment: try `git pull` on the vcpkg repository. I had several linking issues with cmake in the past and updating the vcpkg repo magically fixed them.
Also make sure that the library is actually installed. I noticed that i sometimes need to install the same package twice for it to appear in `vcpkg list`

Comment: @sr3, are trying to cross-compile your application for windows? Or you end goal is to have OSX Bundle?

Answer (score 0):

`-L` is for directories, and `-l` is for individual library files. I see you have mixed `.a` files with directories. You'll need to fix that.

Comment: The `wxWidgets_LIBRARIES` variable is automatically set by `find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)`. I didn't make it. Are you saying they made an error?

Comment: @sr3 Hmm..maybe that's not the issue after all.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to debug cmake configure with `--trace-expand` and see who is setting `wxWidgets_LIBRARIES` to a incomplete and very strange generator expression `libjpeg.a>;libjpeg.a>;libpng.a>;libpng16d.a>;`

Another suspicious thing is that your library paths contain `packages/wxwidgets_arm64-osx` which indicates either wrong usage of vcpkg or there is a `-config.cmake` involved which was not fixed by vcpkg. (everything vcpkg finds via cmake should be  living in `/installed/<triplet>`)